# "Oneway" Replication from Oracle DB to TimesTen

Tags: oracle, replication, timesten

currently I'm really stuck into a problem and I not able to finde a nice way to realize that.

I need a suggestion to replicate from oracle db (some tables) to a TimesTen. A connection is only possible from Oracle DB to Timesten.

I tried the following possibilities and I think they won't work, because at no time I can realize a connection from TimesTen to Oracle Database.

- Active/Passive with Subscribers (On the subscriber will be done a clone, so this connection is not possible) And overall, active passive is oversized.
- TT replication with subscribers over replication sheme: could be possible. From what I saw there will be a connection initiated from master to subscriber. But, I don't know how to get the data from oracle db into TT without using Cache groups. So this possibility it out too, because from what I got that is not possible.

Has anyone a suggestion. I will be very thankful for any idea.

Comment: Maybe you need Oracle In-Memory Database Cache instead?

Comment: What versions of Oracle and TimesTen are you using?

Comment: @Colin'tHart TimesTen is a IMDB, isnt it?

Comment: @kevinsky Oracle 10 and TimesTen I will use whats fit to it.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible (but not simple).
I just made the implementation of ORACLE to TimesTen real time replication.
The solution is based on ORACLE LogMiner utility. Using this tool you can generate the ORACLE transactions in a real time and then ship them to the program (TimesTen side) which will read and apply those transactions to the TimesTen database. The synchronization point is provided between ORACLE and TimesTen by another intermediate ORACLE database. This is very general description, but I can share with you the details if you wish...